# disable check on a row click in DetailsList

Tags: reactjs, office-ui-fabric

I want to use the check column to select which products to put into a shopping cart. In the same time, I'd like clicking on the row to just open a product view without making a selection.

Currently, if I click on the row, all other rows are unselected and the row I clicked on is selected.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`SelectionZone` component](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/blob/1b9405b3b64839975e16ee1fad04d7868d9e3b99/packages/office-ui-fabric-react/src/utilities/selection/docs/SelectionOverview.md) `data-selection-disabled` attribute could be utilized for that matter which :

> allows a branch of the DOM to be marked to ignore input events that
>   alter selections.

The following example demonstrates how to disable selection for row fields but to preserve it for check column. The solution is to place the rendering of row fields (`DetailsRowFields` component) wrapped  with element `<span data-selection-disabled={true}>` to prevent row selection:

```
export default class DetailsListCustomSelectionExample extends React.Component<any,any> {
  constructor(props: {}) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
    this.renderRow = this.renderRow.bind(this);
  }

  public render() {
    return (
      <DetailsList
        onRenderRow={this.renderRow}
        selectionMode={SelectionMode.multiple}
        items={items}
        setKey="set"
        columns={buildColumns(items)}
      />
    );
  }

  private renderRow(props: IDetailsRowProps) {
    return <DetailsRow rowFieldsAs={this.renderRowFields} {...props} />;
  }

  private renderRowFields(props: IDetailsRowFieldsProps) {
    return (
      <span data-selection-disabled={true}>
        <DetailsRowFields {...props} />
      </span>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is [a demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/mjwz97pqpx)